# UITextField custom input

Tags: ios, objective-c, textfield

I created an app that has its own keypad. The keypad (must be the only source of input) is required to input numbers into two text fields as shown:

[image]

The soft keyboards apears in my app as follow:

[image]

I do not want the soft keyboard to appear when the user presses on any of the text fields. The following is my code:

For ViewController.h

```
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UITextField *fixedPrice;
    IBOutlet UITextField *discountRate;
    IBOutlet UITextField *savedPrice;
    IBOutlet UITextField *finalPrice;
    IBOutlet UIStackView *customKeyboard;

}

@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet GADBannerView *bannerView;

-(IBAction)dotButtonPressed;
-(IBAction)digitButtonPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)zeroButtonPressed;
-(IBAction)backspaceButtonPressed;

-(IBAction)calculatePressed;
-(IBAction)clearAll;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *fixedPrice;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *discountRate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStackView *customKeyboard;

@end
```

For ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize fixedPrice;
@synthesize discountRate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    fixedPrice.delegate = self;
    discountRate.delegate = self;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    fixedPrice.inputView = self.customKeyboard;
    discountRate.inputView = self.customKeyboard;

    //fixedPrice.inputAccessoryView = _customKeyboard;
    //discountRate.inputAccessoryView = _customKeyboard;

    [fixedPrice becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

The following image shows the connection to the outlet:
[image]

in my ViewController.m , I am getting the following warning (I am not sure if it is related):

[image]

Considering the above, the keyboard still show up. Any ideas?

EDIT (Crash log):

```
2018-03-12 21:00:58.966215+0300 Diskon[261:8180] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
2018-03-12 21:00:59.241857+0300 Diskon[261:8089] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2018-03-12 21:00:59.242550+0300 Diskon[261:8089] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2018-03-12 21:00:59.371628+0300 Diskon[261:8089] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-03-12 21:00:59.374741+0300 Diskon[261:8089] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-03-12 21:00:59.497213+0300 Diskon[261:8172] 4.8.1 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.40009000 started
2018-03-12 21:00:59.497706+0300 Diskon[261:8172] 4.8.1 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
2018-03-12 21:00:59.812086+0300 Diskon[261:8172] <Google> Advertising tracking may be disabled. To get test ads on this device, enable advertising tracking.
2018-03-12 21:00:59.837680+0300 Diskon[261:8089] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x107526090 V:[GADBannerView:0x1019fa3b0]-(5)-[UILabel:0x107521d90'%']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1075261e0 UILabel:0x107521d90'%'.centerY == UILabel:0x107520070'Kalkulator Diskon'.centerY   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x107526400 UILabel:0x107521d90'%'.lastBaseline == UILabel:0x107520070'Kalkulator Diskon'.lastBaseline   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1075266a0 V:[GADBannerView:0x1019fa3b0]-(5)-[UILabel:0x107520070'Kalkulator Diskon']   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x107526090 V:[GADBannerView:0x1019fa3b0]-(5)-[UILabel:0x107521d90'%']   (active)>

    Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
    The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
    2018-03-12 21:00:59.978231+0300 Diskon[261:8089] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x107555f20> should have parent view controller:<ViewController: 0x101877a00> but requested parent is:<UIInputWindowController: 0x102874400>'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x181173164 0x1803bc528 0x1811730ac 0x18a7c2804 0x18b2f74bc 0x18b2f85a0 0x18a73b92c 0x18b2f82fc 0x18b2f025c 0x18a7e1eec 0x18a753994 0x18a752fbc 0x18aaef974 0x18b3a124c 0x18a7ad8c4 0x18a98dc7c 0x18a992a14 0x18ac2e2a8 0x18af06100 0x18ac2df0c 0x18ac2e76c 0x18b3b37c0 0x18b3b3664 0x18b1212cc 0x18b2ba3cc 0x18b12117c 0x18af05760 0x18a991158 0x18ada6dbc 0x1838361f0 0x18383eaf8 0x100d1928c 0x100d259e4 0x18386a7f8 0x18386a49c 0x18386aa38 0x18111b77c 0x18111b6fc 0x18111af84 0x181118b5c 0x181038c58 0x182ee4f84 0x18a7915c4 0x1009309d4 0x180b5856c)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    (lldb)
```

Comment: Are you sure that your customKeyboard it's not nil? if it's nil the default keyboard appear.

Comment: my customKeyboard is a UIStackView (it contains sub stackview of buttons)

Comment: I am getting the following warning as well: Autosynthesized property 'customKeyboard' will use synthesized instance variable '_customKeyboard', not existing instance variable 'customKeyboard' in my ViewController.m

Comment: I know it, I see your code. But do you connect the IBOutlet?  Your code is fine (You can proof it using other view) if your input view is nil them the keyboard will appear. Check that your cutomKeyboard it's not nil.

Comment: please check the attached image at the bottom. It is connected right?

Comment: I also have @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStackView *customKeyboard; defined just before "@end"

Comment: I added above my ViewController.h full code. @Kevinosaurio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base to your comments:

Remove `IBOutlet UIStackView *customKeyboard;` from `@interface`

And use:

```
fixedPrice.inputView = _customKeyboard;
```

Or:

```
fixedPrice.inputView = self.customKeyboard;
```

Comment: the app crash and does not start when implementing the above. I updated my question and added the crash log.

Comment: I edited my question and added my ViewController.m full code

Comment: The crash is because the app try to add the customKeyboard twice. Because it's already added in the view. If you don't need to show the view like a keyboard and you want to show it statically. You need to use a empty View as imputView `fixedPrice.inputView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]`. If you need to show it like keyboard effect you need to remove the customKeyboard from the view.

Comment: I love you man... this is a solution after 2 weeks of hustle ... really appreciate your support